# Relate a string name in a list with a file pattern to a file without actually traversing to its system directory

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to relate a string name in a list with a file pattern to a file without actually traversing to its system directory.

In the below example, file1 is related to pattern2 and file 2 is related to pattern1.

```
filenames = ["FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_[0-9]*.dat.gz"]

f_ patterns = ["FILE-R_*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_*.dat.tgz", "FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_20010121.dat.gz","FILE-R_34565_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_20140531_190158.dat.tgz"]

for filename in filenames:
    if filename in f_patterns:
         print "File found corresponding to the file pattern".
```

I don't want to traverse through the directory level and do this as there are lots of files to traverse to.

Can I achieve this through `re` or another python module?

Comment: To clarify, you already have the file names within that directory that you are interested in?

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder?

Comment: I Want to do a string matching rather than traversing the file directory . Is there a possible way

Comment: Again, do you already have the file names that are in the directory? If not, you have to scan the directory. If so, then there is definitely a way without having to scan it.

Comment: No files reside. I would be interested to find  a way without having to scan it.

Comment: It looks like there are patterns in both `filenames` (for example: [0-9*]) and `f_patterns` (for example: *).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `"FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_[0-9]*.dat.gz"` and `"FILE-R_*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_*.dat.tgz"` are patterns and `"FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_20010121.dat.gz"` and `"FILE-R_34565_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_20140531_190158.dat.tgz"` are filenames, so I've structured my code to account for that.

Also note that `"FILE-R_*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_*.dat.tgz"` would have to be adjusted to `"FILE-R_.*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_.*.dat.tgz"` in order to match the filename you've provided

Given my assumption, this code will do what I believe you're trying to achieve

import re

```
patterns = [re.compile(p) for p in ["FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_[0-9]*.dat.gz", "FILE-R_.*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_.*.dat.tgz"]]
    filenames = ["FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_20010121.dat.gz","FILE-R_34565_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_20140531_190158.dat.tgz"]
    for filename in filenames:
        for pattern in patterns:
            if pattern.match(filename):
                print "pattern {} matches filename {}".format(pattern.pattern, filename)

pattern FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_[0-9]*.dat.gz matches filename FILE-R_WED_CRDM-PING-GEP-HRD_20010121.dat.gz
pattern FILE-R_.*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_.*.dat.tgz matches filename FILE-R_34565_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_20140531_190158.dat.tgz
```

Comment: This pattern doesnt get matched - "FILE-R_*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_.*.dat.tgz". I am not sure why this needs modification after all.

Comment: @HeninRK apologies, I missed a `.` that needed to be added: both patterns now match.  It might be worth reading up on (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)[python regex syntax] since it looks like you're using shell-style regexs which differ from python regexs

Comment: Am still not able to figure out why the "FILE-R_*_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_*.dat.tgz" cannot be matched with FILE-R_53545453_COMPONENT-DISCCC_PROBLEM_20165434.dat.tgz file.

@Nolen Royalty can you please edit the code which you could find the pattern for

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see if a file name (i.e., a string) matches any one of a list of file name patterns then you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

for filename in filenames:
    if any(re.match(pattern, filename) for pattern in f_patterns):
        print "File name", filename, "matches a pattern."
```

Of course, the patterns have to be valid regex patterns.